# How to avoid Big Query nesting date values in JSON?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using Standard SQL with Big Query and everything is working fine, except my dates are in a nested structure and I have no idea why Big Query is doing that.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT
  DATETIME(salesData.date_utc, "EST") AS DateEST,
  salesData.serial_no AS MachineID
FROM
  sales.sales_all AS salesData
WHERE salesData.date_utc > "2018-05-26T05:00:00" AND salesData.date_utc 
< "2018-05-27T04:59:59"
ORDER BY salesData.date_utc DESC
```

When I'm downloading the results as JSON it's all fine:

```
{"DateEST":"2018-05-26T23:57:58","MachineID":"1708FB0000009-B"}
{"DateEST":"2018-05-26T23:52:07","MachineID":"1710FB0000034-B"}
```

But if I'm using Google Cloud Functions and pull the data, it results in a nested JSON.

```
[
    {
        "DateEST": {
            "value": "2018-05-26T23:57:58"
        },
        "MachineID": "1708FB0000009-B"
    }, ...
```

Here's part of my Cloud Function code:

```
const options = {
    query: sqlQuery,
    useLegacySql: false, // Use standard SQL syntax for queries.
};

bigquery
    .query(options)
    .then(results => {
      const rows = results[0];
      response.json(rows);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
      response.send(500);
    });
```

Comment: After hours I figured it out: you have to CAST the DATETIME object like this:


`CAST(DATETIME(salesData.date_utc, "EST") as STRING) as DateEST`

Comment: I think your answer is valid and you can answer you own question when you get 15 rep point as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so the community could have more visibility about this answer. If you prefer, I can post it as a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) answer.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved by casting the `DATETIME` object as a `string`:

```
CAST(DATETIME(salesData.date_utc, "EST") as STRING) as DateEST
```